# How To Set TabPage on start?

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

I have a TabControl with three TabPages. The initial start of the app opens always the first TabPage on the left side. For me it's necessary to set the starting TabPage (for example the second one).

Of course, I know about possibilities to change the tab on start like these:

```
tabControl.SelectedTab = tabPage;
tabControl.SelectTab(tabPage);
...
```

But this code would also activate additional events to fire like TabControl.Selecting, TabControl.Deselecting, TabControl.SelectedIndexChanged etc. — I would really like to prevent this in advance.

What I am looking for is some kind of property in the TabControl like "StartingTabPageIndex" - setting it to 1 would open the second TabPage on start without invoking any unnecessary events.

Comment: You could always add the event handlers after changing the initial tab. Not only the designer could do the magic

Comment: Why not just move the tab to index 0 in the designer and save yourself the trouble?

Comment: @Steve removing/adding events is always an option for that problem but that's not reliable. It's possible we extend the code with more event handler later (perhaps 2-3 months) and forget to consider THIS - side effects can be cruel.

Comment: @Gabe simple answer "because customer is king" ;)

Comment: @PatRyb lol fair enough bud :)

Comment: Well, never had problems with that, to me it seems pretty safe. However its your choice and if you find a better solution let me know the reasons.

Comment: @PatRyb I did actually test my answer (and updated accordingly), unless there's something obscure that I haven't foreseen, the updated answer seems to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the binding with the event handlers from the designer and add them after you have set the initial tabpage

After removing them in the designer (this doesn't delete the event handler code) rebind the event handler in the form load event after setting the required tabpage

```
 tabControl.SelectedTab = tabPage;
 tabControl.Selected += tabControl_Selected;
 .... and so on for the other events to handle....
```

Answer (score 5):

Another option.  Go into the Form Designer, change the SelectedIndex property from 0 to 1:

```
// 
// tabControl1
// 
this.tabControl1.Controls.Add(this.tabPage1);
this.tabControl1.Controls.Add(this.tabPage2);
this.tabControl1.Controls.Add(this.tabPage3);
this.tabControl1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(223, 21);
this.tabControl1.Name = "tabControl1";
this.tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 1;      //  <--   This Line
this.tabControl1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(300, 143);
this.tabControl1.TabIndex = 3;
```

The event handlers aren't connected yet, and making any modifications to the TabControl in the designer doesn't seem to affect that property.  It *seems* safe to change it this way.

Comment: Yep, that's what my answer is based on (just having it on the designer instead of changing the serialized files, which I prefer for Winforms)... in all honesty, I don't know why the standard `TabControl` serializes it at all, because it always serializes at 0 by default (since as you say, changes in the designer don't change the selected index for some reason)

Answer (score 0):

#### Update

I just made a simple test, and `SelectedTab` does not work because it expects the handle to be created on `set`.

However this seems to work:

```
public class MyTabControl : TabControl
{
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
    [Browsable(true)]
    public new int SelectedIndex
    {
        get { return base.SelectedIndex; }
        set { base.SelectedIndex = value; }
    }
}
```

You'll now be able to see `SelectedIndex` in the designer and can set it. It won't change the visible tab in the designer, but it will store the "initial tab index" (zero-based).

It does change `SelectedIndex`, but it does not call the events since events are assigned last in the designer's serialization, so they are never assigned before the change.

#### Old

One option would be having `SelectedTab` serialized. You'd only need to derive your own custom TabControl from `TabControl` and have something like this:

```
public class MyTabControl : TabControl
{
  [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
  public new TabPage SelectedTab {
    get { return base.SelectedTab;  }
    set { base.SelectedTab = value; }
  }
}
```

That way you'll get your designer selected `SelectedTab` as initial.

I haven't tested this, but theory says it should work :-)